# Embed vs reference my dependencies: Best practices for .NET/NuGet package?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm providing a C#/.NET class library to clients within my company as a NuGet package. My library depends upon some other 3rd-party libraries (e.g. [Newtonsoft's excellent Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)).

I'm assuming that the standard way NuGet works is that my package would only include *references* to other NuGet packages I depend upon. The client's Developer Studio will automatically download them when they install my NuGet package in their project.

**Question #1:**

> Can I be certain that Developer Studio will download the versions of
>   those NuGet packages that I was building against and not the 'latest'
>   versions?

**Question #2:**

> Will it cause problems if their project also uses a 3rd-party library
>   that I'm using (like Json.NET), especially if they are using a different version? Does this 'just work', or do I need to do something about this?

Apologies if this is spelled out somewhere, but I've not been able to find specific answers to these questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's clearly laid out in the [Nuspec Reference](https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference)

Specifically:

> **Specifying Dependencies**
>
> Starting from version 2.0, package dependencies can be specified to vary according to the framework profile of the target project. The  element contains a set of  elements. Each group contains zero or more  element and a target framework attribute. **All dependencies inside a group are installed together if the target framework is compatible with the project's framework profile.**
>
> ```
>   <dependencies> 
>    <group>
>       <dependency id="RouteMagic" version="1.1.0" />
>    </group>
>    <group targetFramework="net40">
>       <dependency id="jQuery" />
>       <dependency id="WebActivator" />
>    </group>
>    <group targetFramework="sl30">
>    </group>
> </dependencies>
> ```

Where version is:

> The range of versions acceptable as a dependency. Typically this is
>   just a version number which represents a minimum version. **However a
>   more explicit [version range syntax](https://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning#Specifying-Version-Ranges-in-.nuspec-Files) is supported.**

*(**update**: updated references to more recent version of nuget)*